# question from Sirovich's "Introduction to applied mathematics"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is exercise 20b of Chapter 1 from Sirovich "Introduction to Applied Mathematics": The page with this exercise can also be found here on Google Books:
https://books.google.com/books?id=yOrlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10

> Show that for the harmonic oscillator equation
>   $$\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=\omega^2 x$$
>   $w=x+i\omega \frac{dx}{dt}$ satisfies a single first order differential equation.

As far as I can tell, the $w=x+i\omega dx/dt$ satisifes the **second-order** equation $dw^2/dt^2=\omega^2w$.

How can I find the **first order** equation that $w$ would satisfy?

Comment: Simply speaking $$\left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2}+ \omega^2 \right) =\left( \frac{d}{dt}-i \omega \right) \left( \frac{d}{dt}+ i \omega \right) $$

Comment: Pick a solution in the form $x=w_1+w_2$ such that each of them satisfies the first order equation defined by operators in each bracket. Then their sum satisfies the original equation.

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question: the given equation has the form $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} - \omega^2$$, rather than $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + \omega^2$$.

Comment: you are right. The words "harmonic oscillator" confused me, because the listed equation is not a harmonic oscillator equation, unless $\omega$ is imaginary... Then you just use the usual formula $$\left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2}- \omega^2 \right) =\left( \frac{d}{dt}- \omega \right) \left( \frac{d}{dt}+ \omega \right)$$ But I'm not sure how the given function fits in any case... I'll think about it some more.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just go by the given equation:

$$\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=\omega^2 x$$

If $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ then this is not exactly a harmonic oscillator equation. It has the general solution in terms of hyperbolic functions, or real exponentials:

$$x(t)=A e^{\omega t}+Be^{-\omega t}$$

Writing down the suggested function explicitly:

$$w=A e^{\omega t}+Be^{-\omega t}+i \omega^2 \left(A e^{\omega t}-Be^{-\omega t} \right)=A(1+i \omega^2)e^{\omega t}+B(1-i \omega^2)e^{-\omega t}$$

Which, I believe is **not a solution to any first order ODE**.

---

Let's try a harmonic oscillator equation instead:

$$\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=-\omega^2 x$$

$$x(t)=A e^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}$$

$$w=A e^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}- \omega^2 \left(A e^{i\omega t}-Be^{-i\omega t} \right)=A(1- \omega^2)e^{i\omega t}+B(1+ \omega^2)e^{-i\omega t}$$

**That still is not a solution to a first order ODE.**

---

Now let's try another function instead:

$$u=x+\frac{i}{\omega} \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Now for the HO equation we have:

$$u=A e^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}- \left(A e^{i\omega t}-Be^{-i\omega t} \right)=2Be^{-i\omega t}$$

Which is now a solution to a first order equation:

$$\frac{du}{dt}=-i \omega u$$

---

> My only conclusion: there must be a typo in the book (or several).

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time on this, typo is something that I suspected as well.